# Django Haystack has a blank `text` value

Tags: django, django-haystack

[Reference:](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/debugging.html)

```
>>> from haystack.query import SearchQuerySet
>>> sqs = SearchQuerySet().all()
>>> sqs[0].text # ... or whatever your document=True field is.
```

> If you get back either u'' or None, it means that your data isn’t making it into the **main field** that gets searched. You need to check that the field either has **a template** that uses the **model data**, a model_attr that pulls data directly from the model or a **prepare/prepare_FOO** method that populates the data at index time.

I couldn't understand why my `.text` return nothing. Could someone explain the above notes? More specifically, I don't understand those I highlighted in bold.

Comment: Finally found the issue why the `.text` return nothing. My backend is using `Simple` backend. Basically Simple backend unable to do advance filtering and a lot of features. Thus `.text` is not generated.

Comment: I switched to Whoosh backend and the `.text` is now generated properly. I'll vote to close the question due to many answers.